# Python : Remove the key if its value is lower than 2

Tags: python

There is a list containing 2 dictionaries, if I want to delete the key of 'zxc' that contains a value lower than 2, what should I do in the next step?

```
aa = [{'asd': 'qwe', 'zxc': 5}, {'zxc': 1, 'rty': 'uio'}]

def try_test():
    if 'zxc' < 2:
        del aa['zxc']
```

but it doesn't work.

Comment: shouldn't the if condition be `if aa['zxc'] < 2:`

Comment: aa is a list. The dictionaries are aa[0] and aa[1]. You need to test aa[0]['zxc'] and aa[1]['zxc'] to see whether either one is less than 2. Then delete either aa[0]['zxc'] or aa[1]['zxc'].

Comment: As the comments above, you need a look of some sort as it is a list.

Answer (score 6):

The problem in your code is that `aa` is a list of dictionaries so `aa['zxc']` is not clear.

**Instead you should loop through each index in the list and compare as follows:**

```
aa = [{'asd': 'qwe', 'zxc': 5}, {'zxc': 1, 'rty': 'uio'}]

def try_test():
    for ind in aa:
        if ind['zxc'] < 2:
            del ind['zxc']

    print(aa)

try_test()
```

**Output:**

```
[{'zxc': 5, 'asd': 'qwe'}, {'rty': 'uio'}]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
aa = [{'asd': 'qwe', 'zxc': 5}, {'zxc': 1, 'rty': 'uio'}]

for d in aa:
    if d['zxc'] < 2:
        del d['zxc']

print(aa)
```